# Linq query to linq extension methods

Tags: linq

How to write this linq query using extension methods?

```
var products = from p in db.Products
           join ps in (from pss in db.ProductSpecs
                       where pss.spec_name== "Price"
                       select pss
                       ) on p.id equals ps.product_id into temp
           from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
           orderby t.spec_value
           select p;
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: It's worth taking a look at [LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) and the related pages.

Comment: Are you sure this query operates properly? Did you mean `select t` instead?

Comment: you should give it a try first yourself....that said, run in Debug mode, and put a watch on product.Expression.ToString()...you can see exactly what the real method calls look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get yourself a copy of LinqPad, paste the query into it, execute it and then click on the Lambda tab. It will show you the Method syntax.